# Test have the null IdentityResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, moq

I have the method

```
  public async Task<ActionResult> CreateRole(RoleModel roleViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            RoleModel role = new RoleModel(roleViewModel.Name);

            // Save the new Description property:
            role.Description = roleViewModel.Description; // <--- Here you have assign the Description value

            IdentityResult roleResult = await roleManager.CreateRoleAsync(role);

            if (roleResult.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                AddErrorsFromResult(roleResult);
            }
        }
        return View(roleViewModel);
    }
```

which create the role, it work right, but when i want to make the mock test I have the null IdentityResult. I can't understand what the problem.

my test

```
public async Task CanCreateRoleAsync()
    {
        //arrange
        Task<IdentityResult> successResult = Task.FromResult(IdentityResult.Success);
        Mock<IRoleManagerRepository> mockRole = new Mock<IRoleManagerRepository>();
        Mock<IUserManagerRepository> mockUser = new Mock<IUserManagerRepository>();
        RoleController controller = new RoleController(mockRole.Object, mockUser.Object);

        RoleModel model = new RoleModel { Id = "test-test-test-test", Name = "test", Description = "test user" };

        mockRole.Setup(m => m.CreateRoleAsync(model)).Returns(successResult);

        //action
        ActionResult result = await controller.CreateRole(model);

        //assert
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(RedirectToRouteResult));
    }
```

and the method which create the role

```
public async Task<IdentityResult> CreateRoleAsync(RoleModel applicationRole)
    {
        IdentityResult result = await userRole.CreateAsync(applicationRole);
        return result;
    }
```

null in this point

[image]

and error called `NullReferenceException object reference does not indicate an object instance.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess it is because the input does not match. Your setup uses one RoleModel instance, and then the actual method call uses a different one created inside `CreateRole`.

Set it up so it can take any object:

```
mockRole.Setup(m => m.CreateRoleAsync(It.IsAny<RoleModel>()))
        .Returns(successResult);
```

Comment: thank you i think about it, but forgot how to fix it